# java poi XWPF word - create bookmark in new document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, bookmarks, xwpf

Very many examples exist for reading and editing/replacing bookmarks in XWPF word document.
But I want to create a document and create new bookmarks.
Create document - no problem:

```
private void createWordDoc() throws IOException {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    File tempDocFile = new File(pathName+"\\temp.docx");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempDocFile);
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("testing string ");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();
    }
```

How can I make a bookmark on text "testing string"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not implemented in high level classes of `apache poi` until now. Therefore low level [CTP](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.java) and [CTBookmark](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTBookmark.java) are needed.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBookmark;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordBookmark {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //bookmark before the run
  CTBookmark bookmark = paragraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkStart();
  bookmark.setName("before_testing_string");
  bookmark.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkEnd().setId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

  //bookmark the run
  bookmark = paragraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkStart();
  bookmark.setName("testing_string");
  bookmark.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("testing string ");

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkEnd().setId(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  //bookmark after the run
  bookmark = paragraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkStart();
  bookmark.setName("after_testing_string");
  bookmark.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkEnd().setId(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordBookmark.docx"));
  document.close();

 }
}
```