# how to set bookmark for XWPFRun object in word by poi

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, bookmarks

I am using Word to create templates that contain many variables. I will read and parse the Word document to set bookmarks for the variables. Each variable is a XWPFRun object. How can I set a bookmark for a XWPFRun object?
Below is the response from chatgpt, but CTR doesn't have addNewBookmarkStart and addNewBookmarkEnd.

```
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
    // Check if the run meets your criteria
    if (/* condition */) {
        // Create a bookmark for the run
        run.getCTR().addNewBookmarkStart().setName("bookmark_name");
        run.getCTR().addNewBookmarkEnd();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: TBH I know nothing about Apache POI, so can only make some guesses as to what you're looking for, but no-one else has replied, so maybe previous answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137818/seperated-text-line-in-apache-poi-xwpfrun-object might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [java poi XWPF word - create bookmark in new document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182971/java-poi-xwpf-word-create-bookmark-in-new-document/47184002#47184002) I have shown how to create bookmarks in a new XWPFDocument.

If you look at the document.xml created, you will find:

```xml
<w:p>
 ...
 <w:bookmarkStart w:name="testing_string" w:id="1"/>
 <w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">testing string </w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
 ...
</w:p>
```

The `bookmarkStart` is immediately before the text run and the `bookmarkEnd`  is immediately after the text run in paragraph. All  elements are children of the paragraph elements on same level.

If the need is to bookmark already existent `XWPFRun`s, then one need to insert the `bookmarkStart` immediately before and `bookmarkEnd`  immediately after the `XWPFRun` in `XWPFParagraph`. This only is possible using a `XmlCursor`.

Example:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBookmark;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordBookmarkXWPFRun {
    
 static void bookmarkXWPFRun(XWPFRun run, String name, int id) {
  // insert bookmarkStart immediately before the run
  XmlCursor cursor = run.getCTR().newCursor();
  String uri = CTBookmark.type.getName().getNamespaceURI();
  String localPart = "bookmarkStart";
  cursor.beginElement(localPart, uri);
  cursor.toParent();
  CTBookmark bookmarkStart = (CTBookmark)cursor.getObject();
  bookmarkStart.setName(name);
  bookmarkStart.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(id));
  
  // insert bookmarkEnd immediately after the run
  cursor = run.getCTR().newCursor();
  if (!cursor.toNextSibling()) { // is there a next sibling?
   // if not, go to end of parent element to insert bookmarkEnd there
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.toEndToken();   
  }
  localPart = "bookmarkEnd";
  cursor.beginElement(localPart, uri);
  cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("id", uri, String.valueOf(id));
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx"));
  
  int id = 1;
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
    // Check if the run meets your criteria
    if (/* condition */ true ) { // this will bookmark every single tect run in document
     // Create a bookmark for the run
     bookmarkXWPFRun(run, "bookmark_name_" + id, id++);
    }
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordDocumentBookmarked.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```